# anonymous functions arguments not accessible to inner functions

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

I have been trying to do this

```
function test()
{
    $.getJSON("http://myurl.com",function (data){
        for( i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            test = createElement('img');
            test.onclick = function (){ myotherfun(data[i]); }
        }
    }
}

function myotherfun(data)
{
    alert(data);
}
```

An error message states that `data` isn't covered by the scope.

Can some one explain why this happens?

Comment: The property name is `onclick` not `onClick`. JavaSscript is case sensitive, unlike HTML. Also you have to append the element to the DOM and actually have it load an image.

Comment: There's no `onClick` property. What does your real code look like? And what does the error actually say? I'm guessing it doesn't use the word "scope".

Comment: yes, i will re-edit the code. but the problem isn't about the onclick working. the web-console says 'data[i] is not defined' i assumed it as the variable scope of the function @the system.

Comment: @user2022595: Yeah, I know it's not about the onclick. Point is to provide accurate information.

Comment: @thesystem thanks a lot. my first post my bad. will learn quickly ! :)

Comment: @FelixKling thanks i think the link you referred me to helps :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've edited your question I can see the problem XD

The problem is that the `onclick` function will use the current values of `data` and (more importantly) `i`. So essentially it's looking for `data[data.length]`, which by the definition of `length` doesn't exist.

Instead, you need to "lock" the value of the iterator. Here's how you can do it:

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    // do stuff that relies on i
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: Or just `test.onclick = myotherfun.bind($, data[i]);`

Comment: this works like a charm ! thanks for the quick reply. i should have tried looking into it than wasting your time :)